# Auto login problems with slim

Tags: linux, arm, xterm, raspberry-pi

I have installed Arch and am having problems with the auto login options within slim.conf. I have installed the following X packages:

xorg-server,
xorg-xinit
xorg-twm, xterm
and for the graphics: xf86-video-fbdev

I have also added a user and password, and altered the sudoers file to suit. I have changed the following lines:

# default_user        simone 
# auto_login          no

to:

default_user        jon 
auto_login          yes

I have managed to get the slim login prompt to appear on boot by editing /etc/inittab, but the changes made for bypassing this have not been as successful.

Anybody know what I have missed? Maybe something to do with adding a user to some group?!

Cheers
J

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a problem with the ARM version of Arch and is a raspberry pi thing. A friend of mine is having the same trouble, but has found the latest version includes various fixes. Seems to do the trick.